# How can we mock session values (request.getSession() ) in JUnit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, junit, mockito

```
private BankApp processSelection(HttpServletRequest request,
        String[] facets, String selectedText) {
    DebugUtility.debug(LOG, "Enter into JiraController :: processDashBoardPortFolioSelection()");
    BankApp project = new BankApp();
    List<BankApp> dataAgg = (List<BankApp>) request.getSession()
            .getAttribute(PROJECT_WISE_SESSION);
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(dataAgg)) {
        List<BankApp> projects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String currentProjectId : facets) {
            Project currProject = vendorUtils.getProjectDetails(currentProjectId);
            List<SourceProjectAssocation> sourceSystem = currProject.getSourceSytems("JIRA");
            List<String> jiraProjects = new ArrayList<>();
            sourceSystem.stream().forEach(s -> jiraProjects.add(s.getAssociatedJiraProject()));
            for (BankApp projectData : dataAgg) {
                if (jiraProjects.contains(projectData.getProjectKey())) {
                    projects.add(projectData);
                }
            }
        }
        project = processAllProjectsData(projects);
        project.setProjectKey(selectedText);
        project.setProjectsCount(projects.size());
    }
    DebugUtility.debug(LOG, "project in processDashBoardPortFolioSelection :: " + project);
    DebugUtility.debug(LOG, "Exit from JiraController :: processDashBoardPortFolioSelection()");
    return project;
}
```

How can we write junit test case for this method? The challenge I'm facing here is we need to mock `request.getSession().getAttribute(PROJECT_WISE_SESSION)`. So I tried `when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);` but with `request.getSession()` I'm getting `null`.

Comment: pls, provide formatted code

Answer (score 2):

try something like that

```
@Test
public void test() {
    HttpServletRequest requestMock = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpSession sessionMock = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    Mockito.when(requestMock.getSession()).thenReturn(sessionMock);

    processSelection(requestMock, <and your facets and selectedText here>)

    //do some asserts/verifies here
}
```

Comment: thanks for response Valentyn Anzhurov. i'm trying your solutions

Comment: HttpServletRequest requestMock = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
      HttpServletRequest sessionMock = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
      Mockito.when(requestMock.getSession()).thenReturn((HttpSession) sessionMock);//it's is ok or not

Comment: @KrishGaur no. you can not cast sessionMock (HttpServletRequest under the hood) to HttpSession. Just use my code

Comment: @KrishGaur so what ?

Comment: @Test
 public void testfacets() throws IOException 
 {
  when(service.getData(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
     .thenReturn(getJiraEntity());
  HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(constructReqHeaders());
  ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate
    .withBasicAuth(env.getProperty("username"), env.getProperty("password"))
    .exchange("/api/jira?facets=allProjects&mode=all&selectedtext=AllProjects",
      HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Object.class);
  Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
 }

Comment: whatever code is sended in comment it's working fine for allproject method because here i'm taking value from service class"when(service.getData()) " but whatever code i posted on stackover flow starting it's not working because here i'm taking values from session(request.getSession()). i tried with your code it's also not working with my code....